Spring cloud and spring security dependency problem
I created an Api Gateway with spring boot, but when I add spring security I have this exception:
Description:
The bean 'conversionServicePostProcessor', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/reactive/WebFluxSecurityConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
Action:
Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
This is my pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.6
 

com.javainuse
cloud-gateway-service
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
gateway-service
Spring Cloud Gateway

<java.version>17</java.version>
<spring-cloud.version>2022.0.5</spring-cloud.version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

When I remove one of these dependencies my project works correctly.
I used this config but my security did not work
main:
web-application-type: reactive
main:
allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
